# Problem with file writing/saving in kivy application on ios

Tags: python, ios, iphone, xcode, kivy

I'm making a game in kivy framework. To save high score i use this lines in my App class:

```
def build(self):
    save_file = open("save.txt", "r")
    sm.get_screen('menu').set_score(int(save_file.readlines()[0]))
    save_file.close()
    return sm

def on_stop(self):
    save_file = open("save.txt", "w")
    save_file.write(str(sm.get_screen('menu').high_score))
    save_file.close()
```

When I'm running it in python everything works fine, but when I'm running it on simulator or physical device It's seems to not saving. When in save file is number 55 It reads it.

I get that log when running it on xcode:

```
    2018-09-12 20:57:05.940676+0200 decode[18245:457744] [Common] 
_BSMachError: port 6707; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) 
"Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
    2018-09-12 20:57:05.941114+0200 decode[18245:457744] [Common] _BSMachError: port 6707; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) 
"Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
```

Here is project: https://github.com/KarolBorecki/Decode

Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't do ios dev, but i'm pretty sure you can't write to arbitrarly locations in it. I think you can use the `App.user_data_dir` property to get a path you can write to in a persistent way.

Comment: yeah, I know I've solved this problem, thanks for the answer!